# Customize Sidbar Juery and Laravel but once added even After application restart it should remain in sidebar

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, show-hide, sidebar

I am new to laravel and Web development i am making my a course project. thanx for helping

Its like a System which have different modules related to Inventory and POS and user can add and remove the items from the sidebar through customize setting tab

**As Below Functionality is working**

This Tab customize contain all the modules and along every item there is a checkbox when user click on the item checkbox it should be added to the sidebar and when unchecked it removes from the sidebar

**Required**

What i am Upto when user hit update and refresh page or even logout from the system and log in The Tab should be shown in sidebar

How can i achieve that part? does it relate to db .if yes please give me a way so that i can work

[image]

Code for Customize Tab

```
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar-customize">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="customer" name="customer">
                        <i class="fa fa-print"></i> 
                <span>customer</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


Code of Jquery


 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {

    if(this.checked)
       $('#customer').fadeIn(1000,function(){
             $('#customer').css('overflow', 'none');
       });


    else 
       $('#customer').fadeOut();  

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to this in a project I worked on where the sidebar could be minimized and we wanted this to be persisted across sessions and pages etc.

What we ended up doing was adding a table to keep track of their 'preferences'. This way we could save their choice to the database and then use this when loading the page to decide whether the sidebar should be minimized or not.

In your case, with this module approach - you could implement the same system.

I would create a new table to store the preference for each module in a column, something like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | accounts | inventory | customer | created_at | updated_at |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |         1 |        1 | today      | today      |
|  2 |       2 |        1 |         1 |        0 | today      | today      |
|  3 |       3 |        0 |         0 |        1 | today      | today      |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

This way you can link the module preferences as a relationship on your `User` model and reference it directly in your views.

e.g

```
@if (Auth::user()->modules->accounts)
    //User is currently user ID 1
    show accounts menu
@endif

@if (Auth::user()->modules->accounts)
    //User is currently user ID 3
    do not show accounts menu
@endif
```

Because each value is stored as an integer in the database, and referenced as a 1 for yes and 0 for no, you can use it directly in an `if` statement to decide if it should be shown or not.

Lastly, you just need to update your jQuery to fire an ajax call when the checkbox is clicked to update the setting/preference.

Comment: Great just prefect thank you very much @James that the approach i am Upto i will get back to you after its implementation please follow

Comment: can i not save the date from the laravel call rather than ajax call

Comment: @Malik what do you mean? How would you save it from the Laravel call? If you are saying that you change the preferences and then submit this via a form that Laravel processes then yes, you could do that.

Comment: i have completed the task through the ajax call. i was having problem to debug in js so thats why. but anyhow i completed the task thnx for the help

Comment: the Problem i am having is a conflict as the between the php and Js it like when it fetch data from db it see customer is 1 it display now if i want to change the view that is to remove customer with out hitting customize button as it does nothing becuase there is now above an if condition will not allow the db to change